# Expresiones regulares con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por favor me podrian indicar cual es el error en mi código el declarar esta expresión regular con jquery

```
 var preg = /^([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?)$/;


  $('#numero2').on('input', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(preg,'');  

  });
```

Comment: Sería mejor y mas efectivo que nos indiques que resultado esperas obtener y cual es el comportamiento que da tu código actualmente

Comment: @Yonathan podrias mostrar el html de tu elemento numero2 y el mensaje de error que presentas?

Comment: El error es que sigue aceptando caracteres no numéricos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método `.replace` de javaScript con `\D`, que identifica todos los caracteres que no son dígitos:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Tu código jQuery quedaría así:

```
$('#numero2').on('input', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'');  

  });
```

Para mantener los decimales sería:
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, '');
//Desde el móvil no puedo formatear bien, lo corregiré

Basado en esta [pregunta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862130/strip-all-non-numeric-characters-from-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Si pero necesito agregar los limites de enteros y decimales

Comment: Estoy fuera pero te he añadido la variacion, ¿Puedes probarla a ver si funciona como quieres? Saludos!